# Embedding python in C application : Multiple versions of C Run-Time libraries

Tags: python, c, cpython, msvcrt

I'm working on application which embeds python and I'm dynamically linking python code (cpyhon) to my library (in order to support multiple python versions, hopefully). When I load pythonXY.dll library (let's say it is **python27.dll**) the **msvcr90.dll** (VS 2008 version if I'm not mistaken) will be also loaded as a dependency. Thing is, I now have two versions of CRT libraries loaded into the process (as I'm using **/MD** compiler switch - dynamic CRT linking) :

- **vcruntime140.dll**
- **msvcr90.dll**

I know this is very bad thing - having multiple C runtimes loaded into the same process.

On the other hand, if I use **/MT** switch - statically linked CRT, there is only **msvcr90.dll** loaded upon loading **python27.dll**.

Can anyone tell me if this is a good idea or not?

Generaly speaking, is there any way to deal with this kind of situation - having an application or module built with one CRT version which can load third party libraries (**pythonXY.dll** in my case) that use other CRT versions?

I'm using VS2015 as my dev environment on Windows 10. As project is still in early phase of development, I didn't put any code on github yet.

I'm not so experienced with C, not yet, thus I apologize if my question is poorly written.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7 if your project is in early phase of development?! Python 3.6 is built with a newer Visual Studio!

Comment: The reason I'm using 2.7 version is just a matter of backward compatibility, I think I need to take that into account.

Comment: Backward compatibility with dead code? How about forward compatibility?

Comment: Too broad, but what you write sounds like you are calling for trouble.